# Having issue calculating timeSince due to timeZone confusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am a little bit confused. the server return date is in UTC ISO format, my local time is CST.
so I use toLocaleString() and then subtract the difference but I get a negative number. I rather use react native library rather than installing new libraries such as moment

```
export function timeSince(date) {
//date is 2022-11-07T18:36:39.543 which is UTC, not CST

  date = date.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: "CST",
  });
// somehow stayed 2022-11-07T18:36:39.543

date = new Date(date); 
//Mon Nov 07 2022 18:36:39 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)


Mon Nov 07 2022 12:29:21 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) 
'2022-11-07T18:27:38.03'


 var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - date) / 1000); // -21506
 return seconds

}
```